# ¿Cómo diferenciar el cajero automático del banco, del cajero automático del parking / parqueadero?

Tags: vocabulario, solicitud-de-término

Ayer, mientras conducía de regreso a casa con un acompañante que no domina muy bien el idioma, se produjo esta conversación:

> —¿Vamos ya a casa?
> —Sí, pero antes vamos a ir al cajero.
> —Si vamos al cajero tienes que llevar monedas para poder sacar el coche.

Tras la confusión inicial, me di cuenta de que, mientras que yo me estaba refiriendo al cajero automático que tienen los bancos para sacar dinero, la otra persona se estaba refiriendo al cajero automático que hay en los *parkings* para pagar antes de salir:

[image: cajero automático parking]

El contexto debería haber sido suficiente para deducir que yo me refería al cajero del banco (¿para qué querría ir al del *parking* si no tengo el coche aparcado allí?), pero el caso es que la confusión se produjo, y esto me hizo pensar un poco.

Los cajeros automáticos de los bancos sirven principalmente para sacar dinero. En cambio, los cajeros automáticos de los *parkings* sirven única y exclusivamente para pagar el uso del parking. Es decir, son dos máquinas con funciones más o menos opuestas, y a pesar de ello usamos el mismo término para ambas.

Cabe destacar también que, para el DLE, "cajero automático" es solo el del banco:

> [**cajero automático**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=6eFNou5#2sNNEo7)
>
> 1. m. Máquina que, accionada por el cliente mediante una clave, realiza algunas funciones propias del cajero (‖ encargado de la caja del banco).

Esta definición no representa bien a las máquinas que usamos para pagar un servicio sin intervención humana.

Mi pregunta es: ¿qué otros términos —distintos de "cajero automático"— se usan, o se podrían usar, para referirse a estas máquinas que solo sirven para pagar un servicio y que no tienen nada que ver con un banco?

Comment: En los parking también hay una persona encargada de cobrar, que se le llama "cajero", así que la máquina que hace sus funciones también es un cajero automático.

Comment: Nunca he llamado *cajero* a eso, yo siempre he dicho "la máquina del parking"

Comment: En Colombia decimos "voy al cajero" si es el del banco o decimos "voy a pagar el parqueadero en la máquina/máquinita" si es el otro. Nunca usamos **cajero** para las **maquinas de pago** de los parqueaderos.

Comment: No sé si *cajero automático* debe ser restringido a solo el banco.  Es cierto que allí inició la idea del cajero automático, pero hoy día también los tenemos en los supermercados y en otros lugares.  Creo que solo tienen que ampliar la definición, no que tengamos que diferenciar — en todos los casos, son máquinas que hacen el trabajo de algún cajero/dependiente.

Comment: Lo malo es que en español no existe *Parking* y en honor a que el sitio está dedicado al uso correcto del español considero que no se debe llamar a algo en inglés cuando la palabra en español claramente existe.

Comment: Oops. Retiro lo dicho dado el enlace del dle. De todas formas es ridículo que el dle la recoja, primero como un sinónimo perfecto de una palabra del español y segundo que diga que la tomamos del francés que la tomó del inglés.

Comment: @DGaleano En realidad, lo de que viene del inglés vía el francés tiene sentido. En francés hay muchas palabras que son falsos anglicismos. _Parking_ es una de ellas. En inglés lo normal es decir "parking lot" o "car park". Quizás _parking_ la inventamos independientemente, pero no es ridículo pensar que haya venido del francés.

Comment: @MarianoRuggiero si A=B y B=C entonces A=C.

Comment: El hecho de que esos carteles en la foto digan "Cajero Automático" parece indicar que estás en una región donde ese término tiene un significado adicional, que en otras partes no tiene. Probablemente no te quede más remedio que desambiguar con palabras adicionales: "cajero automático del banco/del estacionamiento". En otras regiones, para el estacionamiento no usamos "cajero automático", sino "terminal de autoservicio", "caja de autoservicio", y mil variantes más, pero si en la tuya le agregaron ese significado a "cajero automático"... no te va a quedar mucha opción.

Comment: A menudo se usa parquímetro para el cajero del parking.

Answer (score 1):

Yo no me referiría como "cajero" a la máquina que acepta pagos en un estacionamiento, sino como "caja" o "caja automática".  El "cajero automático" es exclusivamente el del banco.